# Set max_execution_time for specific controller in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Using `ini_set()`, I can expand the *maximum execution time* of a script. In **Symfony2**, I can add `ini_set` to `web/app.php` and `web/app_dev.php` to apply the increased execution time to all controllers.

But in this case, I only want to expand the *maximum execution time* for one specific controller action in **Symfony2**. I'd rather not give other actions the possibility to run for a longer time than necessary.

I tried adding the `ini_set` at the top of the action function in the controller, but that doesn't seem to work. Any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can disable the PHP timeout limit with the `set_time_limit` function. More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

as Example:

```
class TaskController extends Controller
{

    public function longTaskAction()
    {
        set_time_limit(0); // 0 = no limits
        // ..
    }
}
```

Comment: The OT wrote that this approach didn't work (for whatever reasons) so I'm not sure it's really helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, accepted :). @matteo the ini_set approach didn't work, this seems to be working tho!