# Run console command behind in Symfony 3.2

Tags: symfony, console, command

I'm trying to run a command in symfony 3.2 meanwhile the page works normaly.

I need to execute this process behind because it might take long time, and server configuration "max_execution_time" errors me, and I can't change this configuration, this might take like 3h long.

I created a personalized command and I call it by going on an specific url, but when I do the "run" in the controller, it keeps loading and gives me server time error.

What I want is to keep the command running by behind.

Comment: Is not a great options but you can try to take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720586/set-max-execution-time-for-specific-controller-in-symfony2/35724307#35724307

Comment: If you have to trigger this in code you could use the [process component](https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously) to call `php bin/console app:my:command` asynchronously. Otherwise just trigger the command via cron.

Comment: Have a look at this nice tutorial https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/02/05/how-to-run-symfony-processes-asynchronously/ I have used this in an example https://gist.github.com/FabianSchmick/c32965ffc3a2d84b148c21332f1d96e3